# Creating a generic method in IEnumerable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, generics

Ok, so a little background information.
I had a method that looks like this:

```
private static IEnumerable<T> Yield<T>(this IEnumerable<T> models, int numberResults) => numberResults > 0 ? models.Take(numberResults) : models;
```

and this was working fine for my project. My project was **not** using **Entity Framework**. But now it has **Identity Framework** and thus it now uses **Entity Framework**.

I have the need now to list some **Users** but use that same function above.
My method for that looks like this:

```
public async Task<List<UserViewModel>> ListByQueryAsync(string query, int yield)
{

    // Put our query in lowercase
    var loweredQuery = query.ToLower();

    // Get our users and search
    var users = base.Users.Where(m => m.UserName.ToLower().Contains(loweredQuery) || m.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(loweredQuery) || m.LastName.ToLower().Contains(loweredQuery)); //.Yield(yield);

    // Return our users as a list
    return await users.Select(m => UserFactory.Create(m)).ToListAsync();
}
```

the **users** variable is **IQueryable** which (if I am correct) implements **IEnumerable** and also, if it is converted to any concrete class it will execute the **SQL**. So I would like to get a list of users then use my static method to **Yield** the amount of results.
At first I simply copied the method above and wrote this:

```
private static IQuerable<T> Yield<T>(this IQuerable<T> models, int numberResults) => numberResults > 0 ? models.Take(numberResults) : models;
```

This works fine, but being an advocate of DRY principles I decided that I have repeated the same method, so I figured because **IQuerable** implements **IEumerable** I would be able to write a private method that can handle bot public methods. So I wrote this:

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Yield<T>(this IEnumerable<T> models, int numberResults) => models.YieldEnumerable(numberResults);
    public static IQueryable<T> Yield<T>(this IQueryable<T> models, int numberResults) => models.YieldEnumerable(numberResults);

    /// <summary>
    /// Lists database entities by a number of results or lists them all 
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The generic entity to list</typeparam>
    /// <param name="models">The query to yield</param>
    /// <param name="numberResults">The number of results to yield</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static IEnumerable<T> YieldEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> models, int numberResults) => numberResults > 0 ? models.Take(numberResults) : models;
}
```

And now I get an error stating :

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Linq.IQuerable'.

I could cast the IQueryable as a list or something, but that would mean that my **Yield** method would actually execute the **SQL** and I don't want it to do that. 
Does anyone know how I can get around this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can solve this by just changing the methods around a bit like this:

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Yield<T>(this IEnumerable<T> models, int numberResults) => models.AsQueryable().YieldQueryable(numberResults);
    public static IQueryable<T> Yield<T>(this IQueryable<T> models, int numberResults) => models.YieldQueryable(numberResults);

    /// <summary>
    /// Lists database entities by a number of results or lists them all 
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The generic entity to list</typeparam>
    /// <param name="models">The query to yield</param>
    /// <param name="numberResults">The number of results to yield</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static IQueryable<T> YieldQueryable<T>(this IQueryable<T> models, int numberResults) => numberResults > 0 ? models.Take(numberResults) : models;
}
```

It compiles and the users are still returned as **IQuerable** so it looks like it works.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it does not work is you actually are calling two different `Take` methods from two different classes.

Your `Yield<T>(this IEnumerable<T> models, int numberResults)` is calling [`public static IEnumerable<TSource> Take(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int count)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx) from the [`System.Linq.Enumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Your `Yield<T>(this IQuerable<T> models, int numberResults)` is calling [`public static IQuerable<TSource> Take(this IQuerable<TSource> source, int count)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300906(v=vs.110).aspx) from the [`System.Linq.Queryable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Notice the return type is different, the error you where getting was because your 2nd function needed to return a `IQueryable<T>` but `YieldEnumerable<T>` only returns a `IEnumerable<T>`. And while you can implicitly cast a `IQueryable<T>` to a `IEnumerable<T>` you can't go the other way.

The work around you posted in your answer is forcing both methods go through `Queryable.Take`, internally `Queryable.Take` is creating a wrapper that ends up calling `Enumerable.Take` for your `IEnumeable` version.

However personally, I would just leave it as two methods, you are not violating DRY because you are calling two separate methods `Enumerable.Yield` and `Queryable.Yeild`. The point of DRY is to decrease code complexity, using the wrapper is just introducing overhead and increasing code complexity by introducing 50% more code (3 lines instead of 2).

Comment: NOTE: doing `public static IQueryable<T> Yield<T>(this IQueryable<T> models, int numberResults) => models.YieldEnumerable(numberResults).AsQueryable();` would ave been bad to do too. This would cause the database to return all rows to the client then do the `.Take` in memory. Also any `.Where`, `.Select(` or other `IQueryable<T>` operations that happen after a `Yield` would also not be part of the SQL query that happens on the server.